# how to create a Java List of two integers

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Hello I am new to java and I am trying to create a list like

```
List<Int, Int> list = new List<Int, Int>();
```

the first int is the value and the second int is the finished time. I want to be able to read from a file and save in my list, So can I later get the finished time or value list in a sorted way. I am going to ue these two list together so when the first one is sorted the second one also needs to be sorted accordingly.

If I use `HashMap` I cant add duplicate values, can someone help me please?
I tried with `TreeMap` but it also didnt work.

Comment: @janos if I am reading from file usin sanner can I do this:  Arrays.asList(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());  and also can I make 2 seprate arraylist later?

Comment: @janos hw do u initialize such list?

Answer (score 7):

You should create a class to wrap your values. Something like:

```
public class IntPair {
     public int value;
     public int time;
}
```

should do. You can then add a constructor, a compare method for sorting, and whatever other functionality you need.

Create the list as follows:

```
List<IntPair> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: you can also do a list of arrays :  Object[][] o=new Object[1][1]; ArrayList al=new ArrayList();al.add(o);

Comment: Parsing the values from a text file is a completely different matter and depends on the format of the file.

Comment: your class inPair can implements comparable, then you will be able to sort your list using Collections.sort(arrayList); to implements comparable, you need to add a compareTo(IntPair) method in your inPair class

Answer (score 2):

Using java inbuilt Pair class. `ArrayList` or any List of pairs can be constructed. you need to import `javafx.util.pair` for that. Similarly for 3 values. Use java's Triplet class.

eg: `Pair p=new Pair(1, 2);`

`ArrayList` or any List of these pairs can be constructed easily now

Answer (score 0):

The 'lazy' way you could create an `ArrayList<Integer[]>` at each index you add an array of 2 places holding the value and the time ex `new Integer[]{val,time}` and then you can sort the arraylist using the Collection.sort and with the help of a `Comparator`

Here is a small example :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer[]> values = new ArrayList<>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        // just for testing I add random values but you
        // should add your values you read from your file
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            values.add(new Integer[] { rand.nextInt(100), rand.nextInt(100) });
            System.out.println(values.get(i)[0] + "\t" + values.get(i)[1]);
        }

        // Let's sort our ArrayList looking at the first index of each array
        // which holds the value
        Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
            public int compare(Integer[] array1, Integer[] array2) {
                return array1[0].compareTo(array2[0]);
            }
        });

        // Print the results 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(values.get(i)[0] + "\t" + values.get(i)[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
82  21
3   54
60  73
14  35
45  30
16  30
8   19
62  43
67  51
7   34


3   54
7   34
8   19
14  35
16  30
45  30
60  73
62  43
67  51
82  21
```

Comment: how can I for example the the values at 0 into an arraylist?